# modeling changing items in market basket analysis

Tags: r, sequence-analysis, marketing, apriori

I'm performing a "dynamic" market basket analysis where a customer transaction is traced from the beginning (here it has an initial basket of product) to the finalized purchase (where there is the final basket) but he can change the items in the basket time by time and it is all traced. How can I model such dynamics?

Comment: I think this is practically impossible to answer the question as written because it depends on what the goal of the analysis is. What is it that you want to know by analyzing the purchasing path?

Comment: Yes it is... The purchasing path.

Comment: If all you are interested is the purchasing path, and your program tracks what products are put in/deleted until the customer clicks to pay, then there is nothing to analyze. You program already gives you the purchasing path, so I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Let me take a guess at what you want. You want a market basket analysis that looks at a collection of items in-basket and predicts  the outgoing, the new incoming, and the final purchased. Do you expect to predict from the first basket the entire path or simply predict at every change?

Comment: Bradsher, you did understand what I would. I could explore both approaches (possibly in R... ;.) )